# memory issues with UIImage when we load 2000 images

Tags: iphone

I'm trying to run an animation by changing the images of my UIImageView . I need about 200 images of 24K to create a 5 sec animation. I am able to load all the images into the memory (into an NSArray), but when I start the animation (switching the UIImage of the UIImageView) - after about 60 images I get a memory warning and if I continue displaying images the app crashes.

Comment: 2000 (title) or 200 (desc) images?

Answer (score 2):

Just because your image files are 24Kb on disk, doesn't mean that is the amount of memory they will take up.

If you have an image that is 480x960 with 1 byte per pixel, that may only be a small file size due to compression (jpeg, for example), but when it is in memory in your app, it will be 450KB. Multiply that by 60 (the point at which you get the memory warning) and you will see that is approx 27MB.

If your images are larger, or have a greater colour depth, then obviously they will consume more memory. I think I read once that iOS gives you a memory warning when you hit 22Mb, but that includes other memory allocated to your app for other things as well.

And just because your app "loads" the images into the array, doesn't mean it actually loads it into memory, or expands it until it really needs it.

So, to calculate how much memory your image is going to use, don't look at the file size, but instead work it out from the image dimensions.